# Iterate through nested json array in angular controller and get unique values

Tags: arrays, json, angularjs

I need to iterate through nested json array which looks like that

```
[
  {
    "title": "EPAM",
    "technologies": [
        "PHP",
        ".net",
        "Java",
        "Mobile",
        "Objective-C",
        "Python",
        "Ruby"
    ],
    "location": "Belarus",
    "city": "Minsk" 
  },
  {
    "title": "Parallels",
    "technologies": [
        "PHP",
        "Java",
        "C++",
        "iOS Development",
        "C#",
        "Ember.js"
    ],
    "location": "Russia",
    "city": "Moscow" 
  }
]
```

What I want is to iterate through list of technologies in each company and then return a list of unique values. I failed, however, to access a single company in company arrays in the controller. It looks like this so far

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('CompaniesController', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('json/companies.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.companies = data; // get data from json

        $scope.techStack = []

        $scope.companies = data.query(function(companies) {
            console.log(companies); //I expected to see data here
        });
    });

  }
]);
```

Apparently I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: To be honest you're asking one question initially, and then what you show in your controller is not nearly relevant to the first part of your question. However I think you can get at what you want by a couple of for loops and [a helper method](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use angular's forEach:

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('CompaniesController', ['$scope', '$http', 
      function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('json/companies.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.companies = data; // get data from json
              angular.forEach($scope.companies, function(item){
                   console.log(item.technologies);  
               })
            });
        });

      }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 6):

If you need only to display nested array on UI, you can do that straight in view
e.g.

```
            <tr ng-repeat="i in Items">
                <td valign="top">{{i.Value}}</td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <table>
                        <tr ng-repeat="c in i.Children">
                            <td>{{c.Value}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to loop through array in AngularJS, you can simply use [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach). For example,

```
angular.forEach(companiesList, function(company) {
    //Here you can access each company.
});
```

I have made a simple demo based on your code that list "Companies" and *unique* "Technologies".

***[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/dnBXGfvp8Xtds7Wa1zsD?p=preview)***

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('CompaniesController', ['$scope', '$http', 
  function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('json/companies.json').success(function(data) {
        $scope.companies = data; // get data from json

        $scope.techStack = []

        angular.forEach($scope.companies, function(item){
            $scope.techStack = item.technologies;
            var uniqueTech = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.techStack.length; i++)
            {
                if (uniqueTech.indexOf($scope.techStack[i]) == -1)
                    uniqueTech.push($scope.techStack[i]);
            }   
            console.log("Unique Technologies : " + uniqueTech);

        })
    });

  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

user angular's foreach function for looping through data.